# Proper location to set up MySQLdb connection in Pylons: app_globals? Thread safety?

Tags: python, mysql, pylons

I want to use MySQLdb in Pylons, but can't figure out where to actually connect. It would seem that making the connection in app_globals.py would be convenient:

```
class Globals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect()
```

Then controllers can access the db via the globals. However, this seems to lead to problems with 'MySQL has gone away' errors, and crashes with concurrent requests, so I'm thinking that this is bad because of thread safety.

What is the best way to do this? Should each controller open and then close a MySQL connection? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use default for Pylons SQLAlchemy?

Comment: I could, although I don't need to do ORM. Thanks for bringing that up, I'll look at seeing what you can do with SQLAlchemy without ORM. Thanks!

Comment: You can do pretty much anything, it supports direct queries via both its own sql implementation and plain text queries, and works as thin layer above mysqldb library.

Comment: I'm giving things a go with SQLAlchemy, which led to my next question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047735/pylons-sharing-sqlalchemy-mysql-connection-with-external-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments on your question: you should probably use SQLAlchemy's non-ORM features such as the [SQL Expression Language](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/tutorial.html) and the [engine API](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/introducing-the-model-and-sqlalchemy.html#engine-api), which each let you still get some of the benefits of SQLAlchemy without needing to go all the way up to ORM-ness.