# Pylons: Sharing SQLAlchemy MySQL connection with external library

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am running Pylons using SQLAlchemy to connect to MySQL, so when I want to use a database connection in a controller, I can do this:

```
from myapp.model.meta import Session

class SomeController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        conn = Session.connection()
        rows = conn.execute('SELECT whatever')
...
```

Say my controller needs to call up an external library, that also needs a database connection, and I want to provide the connection for it from the SQLAlchemy MySQL connection that is already established:

```
from myapp.model.meta import Session

import mymodule

class SomeController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        conn = Session.connection()
        myobject = mymodule.someobject(DATABASE_OBJECT)
        ...
        conn.close()
```

What should DATABSE_OBJECT be? Possibilities:

1. Pass `Session` -- and then open and close `Session.connection()` in the module code
2. Pass `conn`, and then call `conn.close()` in the controller
3. Just pass the connection parameters, and have the module code set up its own connection

There is another wrinkle, which is that I need to instantiate some objects in `app_globals.py`, and these objects need a database connection as well. It seems that `app_globals.py` cannot use `Session`'s SQLAlchemy connection yet -- it's not bound yet.

Is my architecture fundamentally unsounds? Should I not be trying to share connections between Pylons and external libraries this way? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manage connections yourself - it's all done by SQLAlchemy. Just use scoped session object everywhere, and you will be fine.

```
def init_model(engine):
    sm = orm.sessionmaker(autoflush=False, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=False, bind=engine)
    meta.engine = engine
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(sm)

def index(self):
    rows = Session.execute('SELECT ...')
```

You can pass Session object to your external library and do queries there as you wish. There is no need to call .close() on it.

Regarding app_globals, I solved that by adding other method in globals class which is called after db initialization from environment.py

```
class Globals(...):
    def init_model(self, config):
        self.some_persistent_db_object = Session.execute('...')

def load_environment(...):
    ...
    config['pylons.app_globals'].init_model(config)
    return config
```

Comment: Great information, thanks very much. I like the load_environment approach, that will be perfect. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> What should DATABSE_OBJECT be? Possibilities:

4. pass a "proxy" or "helper" object with higher level of abstraction interface

Unless the external library really needs direct access to SQLAlchemy session, you could provide it with object that has methods like "get_account(account_no)" instead of "execute(sql)". Doing so would keep SQLAlchemy-specific code more isolated, and the code would be also easier to test.

Sorry that this is not so much an answer to your original question, more a design suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Pēteris, that's a good idea generally. In my case, the external library is decoupled from my Pylons apps, and it expects to work off a normal database connection, so it would be too much duplication to provide it with methods for all its database interaction. It would be a nice architecture solution though in some cases.